# Executing 10 threads in parallel in sequence from pool of thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have program which takes the value stored from file and checks online. The maximum parallelism is of 10 threads, after which system crashes.

below is what I am doing currently:

```
threads_value = list()
i = 0
while i < len(ValueList):
    for value in ValueList[i:i + 1]:
        value_read = server_connect_read(channel, value)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=update_value, args=(value_read,))
        thread.setName('Currently running thread' + int(value))
        print(threading.current_thread().getName())
        threads_value.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        i = i + 1
for thread in thread_value:
    thread.join()


def update_value(value_read):
    if value_read.server_connect() is False:
        return False
    print("updating values")
    update = server_read.update_value(old_values.xlsx)
    if value_read.server_disconnet() is False:
        return False
```

Here as per the values in file the threads are started all at once. So If I have more then 20 values, the threads starting after first 10 are not able to connect to server and thread will show disconnected. So not all the values are getting updated.

I am still learning and gone through some suggestions of using pool for threads while limiting number of workers while trying them I see the threads are not starting in sequence manner.

Is there any way were I create pull of threads with sequence starting threads.

***EDIT***

From the pointers received , I have updated code.

```
while i < len(ValueList):
    for value in ValueList[i:i + 1]:
        value_read = server_connect_read(channel, value)
        i = i + 1
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as in_thread:
             in_thread.map(update_value(value_read))

def update_value(value_read):
    if value_read.server_connect() is False:
        return False
    print("updating values")
    update = server_read.update_value(old_values.xlsx)
    if value_read.server_disconnet() is False:
        return False
```

But When threads are getting executed, I only see one thread at time instead of 4. 
Am I missing something.

***EDIT 2***

From answer 
I have made the changes But I am only able to run one thread at time. So I am putting updated code from team. As now for all connect disconnect there is one class is made which needed to be used.

```
List = xlrd.open_workbook(Price_LIST).sheet_by_index(0)
ValueList = List.col_values(0, 2)
max_threads = 4
sems = threading.Semaphore(value=max_threads)
//new update
class UpdateClass(object):

    def run(self):
        threads_value = list()
        i = 0
        while i < len(ValueList):
            for value in ValueList[i:i + 1]:
                value_read = server_connect_read(channel, value)
                thread = threading.Thread(target=update_function(value_read,))
                print(threading.current_thread().getName())
                thread.daemon = True
                threads_value.append(thread)
                thread.start()
                i = i + 1
            for thread in thread_value:
                 thread.join()
def update_value(value_read):
    sems.acquire() // tried to limit the threads 
    value_read = server_connect_read(channel, value)
    if value_read.server_connect() is False:
        return False
    print("updating values")
    update = server_read.update_value(old_values.xlsx)
    if value_read.server_disconnet() is False:
        return False
// Running 5 threads in parallel, 
//Pool(5).map(update_value, ValueList)
```

I have tried to use `daemon` for threads, so that it can create in parallel and gets finished. I have used `print(threading.current_thread().getName())` to see if updates happening in parallel or not, but there also I am able to see only one value. I have also tried from new update to create threads and limit them using semaphore

Comment: " The issue here is threads are started but before one completes the other will start and system will show disconnection." This is not clear. What does "system will show disconnection" mean? Why does that happen when another thread starts? Why do you even want to use threads if running two at a time doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexHall Thank you for response.Sorry for misunderstanding. I have updated my question. System shows disconnection when the server_connect() returns false it will indicate as disconnected.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that a few threads can run at the same time, but not all of them because then it's too much for the server to handle. So yes, make a pool of threads and limit the number to 10 or less, then use Pool.map with update_value.

Comment: @AlexHall Yes, You have understood correctly. I have went through examples over internet but did not helped. So could you please explain with little snippet

Comment: No, try writing code using a thread pool and when it doesn't work ask a question about the code that fails. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @AlexHall Thank you for pointer, I have updated the code. But I see only one thread working at a time.

Comment: This is very unclear. Why are you still using the `run` function instead of the code I gave you? Why are you using a semaphore instead of a thread pool? Your `update_value` no longer makes sense because the variable `value` isn't defined.

Comment: @AlexHall : I have no intention of not using your code and not to disrespect you.  I have updated my code as the new update I have received from my global team. In that I have Tried your function but I can see only one value is getting updated at time but not in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def update_value(value):
    value_read = server_connect_read(channel, value)
    if value_read.server_connect() is False:
        return False
    print("updating values")
    update = server_read.update_value(old_values.xlsx)
    if value_read.server_disconnet() is False:
        return False

Pool(4).map(update_value, ValueList)
```

Comment: Probably late response for the answer, I have tried the solution you have provided I am only able to run one thread at time, not parallel. Also I am editing my code in question as I have class object which I need to use.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Hall, I got it working but when I print process PID's , I am getting same process PID's for number of process created. As that is new one I have created new question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093146/multiple-process-is-not-getting-created-python] Thank you again for help